# Storing dynamic data in variable for future use - Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, data-binding

I am making a simple program where I need to store a certain value of scope for later use. The value of scope itself might change, but then my old variable will come in use and will get the desired value back.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<button ng-click="new()">New Name</button>
<button ng-click="old()">Old Name</button><br/>
{{name}}
<script>
//module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//Controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.new = function(){
        $scope.name = "Lina";
        var store = $scope.name;
        $scope.name = "Peter";
    }
    $scope.old = function(){
        $scope.name = store;
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Expectation:**

```
On click of Old 'Lina' must appear.
```

**Result:**

```
On click of Old "Peter" does not change!
```

Alas, I need some methods to store the value of certain scope object to be used at later stages. Can someone help ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my experience i am doing handling this type of situation using making copy of old data in other variable.

example:

suppose i have a variable 
xyz in my scope 
so i will create a variable in  xyzold.
and in xyzold i will copy that data but coping the data you have to follow following approach.

```
$scope.xyzold = angular.toJson($scope.xyz);
$scope.xyzold = JSON.parse($scope.xyzold);
```

using this code you can make copy of old data n whenever xyz will change no effect will happen to old data

Comment: bs bs ab kya rulaonge kya

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in the scope of `store`

Variables in JavaScript are scoped to the enclosing function when defined with `var`, that means when reading the `store` in `$scope.old` an uninitialized variable is actually read

This would "share" the variable for the whole controller, as the scope will be the enclosing function of the controller definition. The variable is visible in nested functions.

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    var store;
    $scope.new = function(){
        ...
        store = xyz;
```